# how can i open a JFrame from another class with a JButton . For the moment i use a button linked to action listener

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

imp

```
ort java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Menu extends JFrame implements ActionListener

{

      private  JButton btn = new JButton("start now");

       public Menu()throws Exception
        {  
             JFrame os = new JFrame ();
             os.add(btn);
             btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5, 10));

             btn.addActionListener(this);

            os.setSize(822,547);
            os.setBounds(550,300, 700,459);
            os.setVisible(true);
            os.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Container cp = os.getContentPane();             
            JPanel endmessage = new JPanel();

            JLabel mes = new JLabel();
            mes.setIcon (new ImageIcon("backgroundMenu.png" ));

            cp.add(endmessage);
            endmessage.add(mes);
            os.setVisible(true);

          }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)       
         { 
           if (e.getSource() == btn)
           {
            SpaceShipsGamePartThree myFrame = new SpaceShipsGamePartThree();
            myFrame.setVisible(true);

          }
             }

        public static void main(String args[])throws Exception      
         {  
            Menu myFrame = new Menu();

          }

   }
```

//[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsFRO.png)i get the message error: unreported exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown . This class is originally for a menu so it could be linked to the main part of the game .

Comment: Someone has declared that they throw and exception, you must `catch` it, because, I'm assuming you're getting this in the `actionPerformed ` method, you can't change the method signature as it defined by the `ActionListener` interface

Answer (score 1):

Since `SpaceShipsGamePartThree` is throwing the exception, you need to handle it there.  Because you can't change the method signature of `actionPerformed` because it's defined by the `ActionListener` interface, you will need to trap the exception and handle it yourself.

```
@Override 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btn) {
        try {
            SpaceShipsGamePartThree myFrame = new SpaceShipsGamePartThree();
            myFrame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

While this just prints the exception to the console, I'd recommend that you consider using something like `JOptionPane` to at least display some kind of error message to the user so they're not left wondering what went wrong